# Cassandra restart issues while restoring to a new cluster

Tags: cassandra, datastax, restore, cassandra-2.2

I am restoring to a fresh new Cassandra `2.2.5` cluster consisting of 3 nodes.

Initial cluster health of the NEW cluster:

```
--  Address       Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  10.40.1.1   259.31 KB   256          ?       d2b29b08-9eac-4733-9798-019275d66cfc  uswest1adevc
UN  10.40.1.2   230.12 KB   256          ?       5484ab11-32b1-4d01-a5fe-c996a63108f1  uswest1adevc
UN  10.40.1.3   248.47 KB   256          ?       bad95fe2-70c5-4a2f-b517-d7fd7a32bc45  uswest1cdevc
```

As part of the [restore instructions in Datastax docs](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.2/cassandra/operations/opsSnapshotRestoreNewCluster.html), i do the following on the new cluster:

1) `cassandra stop` on all of the three nodes one by one.

2) Edit `cassandra.yaml` for all of the three nodes with the backup'ed token ring information. [Step 2 from docs]

3) Remove the contents from `/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/*` [Step 4 from docs]

4) `cassandra start` on nodes `10.40.1.1`, `10.40.1.2`, `10.40.1.3` respectively.

Result:
`10.40.1.1` restarts back successfully:

```
--  Address       Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  10.40.1.1   259.31 KB   256          ?       2d23add3-9eac-4733-9798-019275d125d3  uswest1adevc
```

But the second and the third nodes fail to restart stating:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: A node with address 10.40.1.2 already exists, cancelling join. Use cassandra.replace_address if you want to replace this node.
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.checkForEndpointCollision(StorageService.java:546) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.prepareToJoin(StorageService.java:766) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:693) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:585) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:300) [apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:516) [apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:625) [apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2016-08-09 18:13:21,980 Gossiper.java:1449 - Announcing shutdown
```

---

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: A node with address 10.40.1.3 already exists, cancelling join. Use cassandra.replace_address if you want to replace this node.
...
```

Eventual cluster health:

```
--  Address       Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  10.40.1.1   259.31 KB   256          ?       2d23add3-9eac-4733-9798-019275d125d3  uswest1adevc
DN  10.40.1.2   230.12 KB   256          ?       6w2321ad-32b1-4d01-a5fe-c996a63108f1  uswest1adevc
DN  10.40.1.3   248.47 KB   256          ?       9et4944d-70c5-4a2f-b517-d7fd7a32bc45  uswest1cdevc
```

---

I understand that the HostID of a node might change after system dirs are removed.

My question is:

Do i need to explicitly state during the start to replace itself? Are the docs incomplete or am i missing something in my steps?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there were stale directories commit_log and saved_caches which i missed to delete earlier. The instructions work correctly with those directories deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Usually on a situation like this, after i do a

$ systemctl stop cassandra

It i will run the

$ ps awxs | grep cassandra

will notice cassandra still has some features up.

I usually do a

$ kill -9 cassandra.pid

and

$ rm -rf /var/lib/cassandra/data/* && /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/*

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: A node with address 10.40.1.3 already exists, cancelling join. Use cassandra.replace_address if you want to replace this node.
```

If you are still facing this above error, that means your cassandra process is running on that node. Login to `10.40.1.3` node firstly. Then follow the following steps-

`$ jps`

You see some processes running. For example:

`9107 Jps
1112 CassandraDaemon`

Then kill the `CassandraDaemon` process by the process id you see after executing `jps`. In my example, here process id `1112` for `CassandraDaemon`.

`$ kill -9 1112`

Then check processes again after a while-

`$ jps`

You will see `CassandraDaemon` will no longer be available.

`9170 Jps`

Then remove your `saved_caches` and `commitlog` and start `cassandra` again.
Do this for all nodes you are suffering with above error you mentioned.